# error: non-static method reception_about() cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, ооп, интерфейс

У меня возникла ошибка, при создании наследования интерфейсов Java.

> Error: non-static method reception_about() cannot be referenced from a static context

Вот весь сам код.

**Main.java**

```
package people;


 public class Main implements People,Position,Unit,Employee {
    @Override
    public void reception_about() {
        String[] array =  {"Контроль за сотрудниками","ПРоверка отчетов"};
        for(int i=0;i<array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i]+"\n");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void list_subordinates() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); // Generated from nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Code/GeneratedMethodBody
    }

    @Override
    public void give_orders() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); // Generated from nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Code/GeneratedMethodBody
    }

    @Override
    public void call_an_employee() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); // Generated from nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Code/GeneratedMethodBody
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.print("Информация о сотруднике\n");
        System.out.print("ФИО "+People.First_name+" "+People.Last_name+" "+People.Middle_name+"\n");
        System.out.print("Дата рождения "+People.Birthday+"\n");
        System.out.print("Пол "+People.Pol+"\n");
        System.out.print("Подраздел "+Employee.unit+"\n");
        System.out.print("Должность "+Employee.position+"\n");
        System.out.print("Зарплата "+Employee.salary+"\n");
        System.out.print("Прийом на роботу "+Employee.reception+"\n");
        System.out.print("Увольнения на роботу "+Employee.release+"\n");
        System.out.print("Название подраздела "+Unit.name_unit+"\n");
        System.out.print("Количество людей в подразделе "+Unit.count_people+"\n");
        System.out.print("Количество рабочего времени "+Unit.time_work+"\n");
        System.out.print("Полная должность "+Position.name_position+"\n");
        Position.reception_about();
    }
}
```

**Position.java**

```
package people;

interface Position extends Unit {
      public String name_position="Директор по маркетингу";
      public void reception_about();
      public void list_subordinates();
      
      public void give_orders();
      public void call_an_employee();
      
}
```

**Unit.java**

```
package people;

interface Unit extends Employee {
    public String name_unit="Маркетинг";
    public int count_people=12;
    public int time_work=8;
    
}
```

**People.java**

```
package people;

/**
 *
 * @author artem
 */
interface People {

    public String Last_name = "Дикарев";
    public String First_name ="Артем";
    public String Middle_name = "Андреевич";
    public String Birthday="06/01/2001";
    public String Pol = "Мужской";
    
    
}
```

**Employee.java**

```
package people;
interface Employee extends People {
    public String unit = "Маркетинг";
    public String position ="Директор";
    public double salary =120000;
   
    public String reception = "21/02/2022";
    public String  release = "No";
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нельзя вызвать нестатический метод как статический.

```
Position.reception_about();
```

Чтобы исправить ошибку нужно создать объект класса `Main` и ссылку присвоить в переменную. Затем использовать эту ссылку для вызова метода этого объекта.

Например:

```
Position position = new Main():
position.reception_about();
```

---

Более подробно можно почитать про статические методы в [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html):

> Язык программирования Java поддерживает статические методы, а также статические переменные.  Статические методы, объявления которых имеют модификатор `static`, должны вызываться с именем класса без необходимости создания экземпляра класса, как в
>
> ```
> ClassName.methodName (аргументы)
> ```
>
> Примечание. Вы также можете ссылаться на статические методы с помощью ссылки на объект, например
>
> ```
> instanceName.methodName (аргументы)
> ```
>
> но это не рекомендуется, потому что это не дает понять, что это методы класса.
>
> Обычно статические методы используются для доступа к статическим полям.  Например, мы могли бы добавить статический метод к классу `Bicycle` для доступа к статическому полю `numberOfBicycles`:
>
> ```
> public static int getNumberOfBicycles () {
>     return numberOfBicycles;
> }
> ```
>
> Не все комбинации переменных и методов экземпляра и класса разрешены:
>
> - Методы экземпляра могут напрямую обращаться к переменным экземпляра и методам экземпляра.
> - Методы экземпляра могут напрямую обращаться к переменным класса и методам класса.
> - Методы класса могут напрямую обращаться к переменным класса и методам класса.
> - Методы класса не могут напрямую обращаться к переменным экземпляра или методам экземпляра - они должны использовать ссылку на объект.  Кроме того, методы класса не могут использовать ключевое слово `this`, поскольку нет экземпляра, на который можно было бы ссылаться.

---

Comment: Чем больше голосов "за", тем лучше понимание как вопроса так и ответа.