# Как отделить логику общения с пользователем от логики самого алгоритма

Tags: java, ооп, static

Нужно отделить логику общения с пользователем от логики самого алгоритма.

```
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.*;
    
    public class TestFinal1 {
        public static Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> adjacentMap = new HashMap<>();
        public static int vertexQuantity;
        public static int edgeQuantity;
        public static int[][] weights;
    /*всё статическое, что противоречит ООП
    нужно разделить логику общения с пользователем от логики самого алгоритма и создать вложенный класс с алгоритмом
    */
        public static Set<Integer> added = new HashSet<>();
        public static Set<Integer> notAdded = new HashSet<>();
        public static List<Edge> maxSpanningTree = new ArrayList<>();
        public static Queue<Edge> edges = new PriorityQueue<>((o1, o2) -> o2.getWeight() - o1.getWeight());
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            inputUndirectGraph();
            System.out.println(findMaxSpanningTree());
        }
    
        public static void inputUndirectGraph() throws IOException {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(bufferedReader.readLine());
            vertexQuantity = Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
            edgeQuantity = Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
            weights = new int[vertexQuantity + 1][vertexQuantity + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < edgeQuantity; i++) {
                stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(bufferedReader.readLine());
                int firstVertex = Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
                int secondVertex = Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
                if (secondVertex == firstVertex) {
                    continue;
                }
                int weight = Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
                if (!adjacentMap.containsKey(firstVertex)) {
                    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    list.add(secondVertex);
                    adjacentMap.put(firstVertex, (ArrayList<Integer>) list);
                } else {
                    adjacentMap.get(firstVertex).add(secondVertex);
                }
    
                if (!adjacentMap.containsKey(secondVertex)) {
                    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    list.add(firstVertex);
                    adjacentMap.put(secondVertex, (ArrayList<Integer>) list);
                } else {
                    adjacentMap.get(secondVertex).add(firstVertex);
                }
                if (weight > weights[firstVertex][secondVertex]) {
                    weights[firstVertex][secondVertex] = weight;
                    weights[secondVertex][firstVertex] = weight;
                }
            }
    
            for (int i = 1; i <= vertexQuantity; i++) {
                adjacentMap.putIfAbsent(i, null);
            }
        }
    
        public static String findMaxSpanningTree() {
            notAdded.addAll(adjacentMap.keySet());
            int startVertex = 1;
            addVertex(startVertex);
    
            while (!notAdded.isEmpty() && !edges.isEmpty()) {
                Edge maxEdge = extractMax((PriorityQueue<Edge>) edges);
                if (notAdded.contains(maxEdge.getEndVertex())) {
                    maxSpanningTree.add(maxEdge);
                    addVertex(maxEdge.getEndVertex());
                }
            }
    
            if (!notAdded.isEmpty()) {
                return "Oops! I did it again";
            }
    
            int resultWeight = 0;
            for (Edge edge : maxSpanningTree) {
                resultWeight += weights[edge.getStartVertex()][edge.getEndVertex()];
            }
    
            return String.valueOf(resultWeight);
        }
    
        private static void addVertex(int vertex) {
            added.add(vertex);
            notAdded.remove(vertex);
            if (adjacentMap.get(vertex) != null) {
                for (Integer adjacentVertex : adjacentMap.get(vertex)) {
                    if (notAdded.contains(adjacentVertex)) {
                        edges.add(new Edge(vertex, adjacentVertex, weights[vertex][adjacentVertex]));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        private static Edge extractMax(PriorityQueue<Edge> edges) {
            return edges.poll();
        }
    }
    
    class Edge {
        int startVertex;
        int endVertex;
        int weight;
    
        public Edge(int startVertex, int endVertex, int weight) {
            this.startVertex = startVertex;
            this.endVertex = endVertex;
            this.weight = weight;
        }
    
        public int getStartVertex() {
            return startVertex;
        }
    
            public int getEndVertex() {
                return endVertex;
            }
        
            public int getWeight() {
                return weight;
            }
        }
```

**РЕД.:**

```
// ПОПРОБОВАЛ ИСПРАВИТЬ ВОТ ТАК, ОШИБКУ ВЫДАЕТ MAIN
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;

public class TestFinal1 {
    public Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> adjacentMap = new HashMap<>();
    public int vertexQuantity;
    public int edgeQuantity;
    public int[][] weights;
    public Set<Integer> added = new HashSet<>();
    public Set<Integer> notAdded = new HashSet<>();
    public List<Edge> maxSpanningTree = new ArrayList<>();
    public Queue<Edge> edges = new PriorityQueue<>((o1, o2) -> o2.getWeight() - o1.getWeight());

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Algorithm.inputUndirectGraph();
        System.out.println(Algorithm.findMaxSpanningTree());
    }

    class Algorithm {
        public  void inputUndirectGraph() throws IOException {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(bufferedReader.readLine());
            vertexQuantity = Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
            edgeQuantity = Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
            weights = new int[vertexQuantity + 1][vertexQuantity + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < edgeQuantity; i++) {
                stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(bufferedReader.readLine());
                int firstVertex = Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
                int secondVertex = Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
                if (secondVertex == firstVertex) {
                    continue;
                }
                int weight = Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
                if (!adjacentMap.containsKey(firstVertex)) {
                    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    list.add(secondVertex);
                    adjacentMap.put(firstVertex, (ArrayList<Integer>) list);
                } else {
                    adjacentMap.get(firstVertex).add(secondVertex);
                }

                if (!adjacentMap.containsKey(secondVertex)) {
                    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    list.add(firstVertex);
                    adjacentMap.put(secondVertex, (ArrayList<Integer>) list);
                } else {
                    adjacentMap.get(secondVertex).add(firstVertex);
                }
                if (weight > weights[firstVertex][secondVertex]) {
                    weights[firstVertex][secondVertex] = weight;
                    weights[secondVertex][firstVertex] = weight;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 1; i <= vertexQuantity; i++) {
                adjacentMap.putIfAbsent(i, null);
            }
        }

        public String findMaxSpanningTree() {
            notAdded.addAll(adjacentMap.keySet());
            int startVertex = 1;
            addVertex(startVertex);

            while (!notAdded.isEmpty() && !edges.isEmpty()) {
                Edge maxEdge = extractMax((PriorityQueue<Edge>) edges);
                if (notAdded.contains(maxEdge.getEndVertex())) {
                    maxSpanningTree.add(maxEdge);
                    addVertex(maxEdge.getEndVertex());
                }
            }

            if (!notAdded.isEmpty()) {
                return "Oops! I did it again";
            }

            int resultWeight = 0;
            for (Edge edge : maxSpanningTree) {
                resultWeight += weights[edge.getStartVertex()][edge.getEndVertex()];
            }

            return String.valueOf(resultWeight);
        }

        private void addVertex(int vertex) {
            added.add(vertex);
            notAdded.remove(vertex);
            if (adjacentMap.get(vertex) != null) {
                for (Integer adjacentVertex : adjacentMap.get(vertex)) {
                    if (notAdded.contains(adjacentVertex)) {
                        edges.add(new Edge(vertex, adjacentVertex, weights[vertex][adjacentVertex]));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private Edge extractMax(PriorityQueue<Edge> edges) {
            return edges.poll();
        }
    }
}

class Edge {
    int startVertex;
    int endVertex;
    int weight;

    public Edge(int startVertex, int endVertex, int weight) {
        this.startVertex = startVertex;
        this.endVertex = endVertex;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public int getStartVertex() {
        return startVertex;
    }

    public int getEndVertex() {
        return endVertex;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }
}
```

Comment: Сделал задание, все работает. Но ревьюер  оставил комментарий "всё статическое, что противоречит ООП нужно разделить логику общения с пользователем от логики самого алгоритма и создать вложенный класс с алгоритмом". Не совсем понимаю как это сделать, а сроки горят. Буду очень благодарен. С ревьюером обратной связи нет могу отправлять только задания

Comment: Уберите все static с  переменных и методов, там где это возможно.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, я убрал все static, вынес в отдельный класс алгоритм. Но у меня теперь psvm подчеркивает в вызванных методах ошибки

Comment: Ошибки добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: я в поле где первый код добавил второй код внизу, как я пытался исправить

Comment: так работать не будет, у вас много необявленных переменных в методах. Также советую почитать [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1378795/204920).

Comment: Какой то странный пример, быть может, Algorithm должен быть отдельным классом, а Edge уже вложенным в него. В таком случае нужно создать экземпляр Algorithm и передать ему созданный экземпляр TestFinal1. Везде где вы обращаетесь к TestFinal1, нужно указывать точку входа через ссылку на этот объект ... Смысл писать такие простыни. так же если вам намекнули на ООП то стоит задуматься о инкапсуляции.

Comment: Если вы убрали `static` из сигнатур методов и полей, значит они"волшебно" превратились в методы/поля _экземпляра_ класса `Algorithm`. Создайте экземпляр `Algorithm alg = new TestFinal1().new Algorithm();` и вызывайте у него методы `alg.inputUndirectGraph(); alg.findMaxSpanningTree();`, и будет щщастье.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переменные из `TestFinal1` перенести в `Algorithm`, а класс `Edge` можно перенести тоже туда.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.*;
   
public class TestFinal1 {
        
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            Algorithm a = new Algorithm();
            a.inputUndirectGraph();
            System.out.println(a.findMaxSpanningTree());
        }
  }  

  public class Algorithm {

 class Edge {
        int startVertex;
        int endVertex;
        int weight;
 
        public Edge(int startVertex, int endVertex, int weight) {
            this.startVertex = startVertex;
            this.endVertex = endVertex;
            this.weight = weight;
        }
    
        public int getStartVertex() {
            return startVertex;
        }
    
        public int getEndVertex() {
            return endVertex;
        }
    
        public int getWeight() {
            return weight;
        }
    }
       Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> adjacentMap = new HashMap<>();
        int vertexQuantity;
        int edgeQuantity;
        int[][] weights;
        Set<Integer> added = new HashSet<>();
        Set<Integer> notAdded = new HashSet<>();
        List<Edge> maxSpanningTree = new ArrayList<>();
        Queue<Edge> edges = new PriorityQueue<>((o1, o2) -> o2.getWeight() - o1.getWeight());

            public  void inputUndirectGraph() throws IOException {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(bufferedReader.readLine());
                vertexQuantity = Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
                edgeQuantity = Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
                weights = new int[vertexQuantity + 1][vertexQuantity + 1];
                for (int i = 0; i < edgeQuantity; i++) {
                    stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(bufferedReader.readLine());
                    int firstVertex = Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
                    int secondVertex = Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
                    if (secondVertex == firstVertex) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    int weight = Integer.parseInt(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
                    if (!adjacentMap.containsKey(firstVertex)) {
                        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
                        list.add(secondVertex);
                        adjacentMap.put(firstVertex, (ArrayList<Integer>) list);
                    } else {
                        adjacentMap.get(firstVertex).add(secondVertex);
                    }
    
                    if (!adjacentMap.containsKey(secondVertex)) {
                        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
                        list.add(firstVertex);
                        adjacentMap.put(secondVertex, (ArrayList<Integer>) list);
                    } else {
                        adjacentMap.get(secondVertex).add(firstVertex);
                    }
                    if (weight > weights[firstVertex][secondVertex]) {
                        weights[firstVertex][secondVertex] = weight;
                        weights[secondVertex][firstVertex] = weight;
                    }
                }
    
                for (int i = 1; i <= vertexQuantity; i++) {
                    adjacentMap.putIfAbsent(i, null);
                }
            }
    
            public String findMaxSpanningTree() {
                notAdded.addAll(adjacentMap.keySet());
                int startVertex = 1;
                addVertex(startVertex);
    
                while (!notAdded.isEmpty() && !edges.isEmpty()) {
                    Edge maxEdge = extractMax((PriorityQueue<Edge>) edges);
                    if (notAdded.contains(maxEdge.getEndVertex())) {
                        maxSpanningTree.add(maxEdge);
                        addVertex(maxEdge.getEndVertex());
                    }
                }
    
                if (!notAdded.isEmpty()) {
                    return "Oops! I did it again";
                }
    
                int resultWeight = 0;
                for (Edge edge : maxSpanningTree) {
                    resultWeight += weights[edge.getStartVertex()][edge.getEndVertex()];
                }
    
                return String.valueOf(resultWeight);
            }
private void addVertex(int vertex) {
                added.add(vertex);
                notAdded.remove(vertex);
                if (adjacentMap.get(vertex) != null) {
                    for (Integer adjacentVertex : adjacentMap.get(vertex)) {
                        if (notAdded.contains(adjacentVertex)) {
                            edges.add(new Edge(vertex, adjacentVertex, weights[vertex][adjacentVertex]));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    
            private Edge extractMax(PriorityQueue<Edge> edges) {
                return edges.poll();
            }
        }
```